# Is there a built-in method for selecting closest n siblings

Tags: jquery

Consider the structure below

[image: Buttons]

What i want is to select closest 9 buttons on clicking on a button and do lets say changing bg colors. And here's my custom code already doing that

```
$(document).on("click", "#footer button", function(){
    var index = $(this).index();
    var len = $("#footer button").length;
    $("#footer button").css({
        "background-color" : "#ccc"
    });
    if (index < 5) $("#footer button:lt(9)").css({
        "background-color" : "#c99"
    });
    else if (index > (len - 6)) $("#footer button:gt(-10)").css({
        "background-color" : "#c99"
    });
    else $("#footer button").slice((index -4), (index + 5)).css({
        "background-color" : "#c99"
    });
});
```

Now, i find using `if .. else ..` blocks for jquery selectors lame somehow. Of course we gotta use it if we have to but in this case do we? Are there any built-in methods to chain for such purpose in jquery?

**[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/x2QJP/)** is the fiddle to play with.

Comment: Have you considered a switch statement?

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's still gonna be including different selectors for each case. What i'm asking if this is possible for building just one selector.

Comment: I'm looking at it now and have thought that using prevUntil() and nextUntil() might be a solution. There is no single answer that I am aware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built in method to do this, but it's easily done without using `if`/`else`:

```
$(document).on("click", "#footer button", function () {
    var that = $(this),
        index = that.index(),
        prev = that.prevAll('button:lt(4)'),
        next = that.nextAll('button:lt(4)');
    that.siblings().removeClass('highlight');
    that.add(prev).add(next).addClass('highlight');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x2QJP/2/).

Incidentally, a simple plugin could be easily created/used:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.rangedHighlight = function(range,highlight) {
        var that = this,
            prev = that.prevAll().slice(0,range),
            next = that.nextAll().slice(0,range);
        that.siblings().addBack().removeClass(highlight);
        that.add(prev).add(next).addClass(highlight);
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#footer').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).rangedHighlight(4,'highlight');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x2QJP/3/).

Unfortunately I hadn't noticed, until it was pointed out in the comments, the necessity of always highlighting the full specified range of elements, even if that offsets the clicked element from the centre of the highlighted section. There doesn't seem to be any way of doing this without using an `if`/`else` of some sort (though I'm trying to simplify it).

While the above remains true (there is no built-in method), I did decide to rewrite the plugin to offer the choice to do so (in case it's of any use to you):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.rangedHighlight = function(opts) {
        var that = this,
            index = that.index(),
            s = $.extend({
                'range' : 9,
                'highlight' : 'highlight',
                'highlightClicked' : false,
                'alwaysShowFull' : true,
                'returnRange' : false
            }, opts),
            eitherSide = Math.floor(s.range - 1)/2,
            all = that.parent().children(),
            leftLimited = index < eitherSide,
            rightLimited = index > all.length - eitherSide - 1,
            rangeMin, rangeMax, returnObject;

        that.addClass(s.highlightClicked, 'string' === typeof s.highlightClicked);

        if (!leftLimited && !rightLimited) {
            rangeMin = index - eitherSide;
            rangeMax = index + eitherSide + 1;
        }
        else if (s.alwaysShowFull && (leftLimited || rightLimited)) {
                rangeMin = leftLimited ? 0 : all.length - s.range;
                rangeMax = leftLimited ? s.range : all.length;
        }
        else if (!s.alwaysShowFull && (leftLimited || rightLimited)) {
                rangeMin = leftLimited ? 0 : index - eitherSide;
            rangeMax = leftLimited ? index + eitherSide + 1 : all.length;
        }

        that.siblings('.' + s.highlight).removeClass(s.highlight);
        all.slice(rangeMin, rangeMax).addClass(s.highlight);

        returnObject = s.returnRange === false ? this : all.slice(rangeMin,rangeMax);

        return returnObject;
    };
})(jQuery);

$('#footer').on('click', 'button', function(){
    $(this).rangedHighlight({
        // Number: number of elements _in total_ to be highlighted:
        'range' : 7,
        // String: the class-name to be applied to selected elements:
        'highlight' : 'highlight',
        // Boolean: shows the full range even if that range 'overlaps'
        // the start/end points:
        'alwaysShowFull' : true,
        // Boolean: return the selected range (true) or the clicked
        // element (true), for chaining purposes:
        'returnRange' : false,
        // String: specific class to add to the clicked element:
        'highlightClicked' : false,
    });
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/x2QJP/10/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional ('ternary') operator (`condition ? conditionIsTrue : conditionIsFalse`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
  - [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
  - [`addBack()`](http://api.jquery.com/addBack/).
  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
  - [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [Greater-than (`:gt()`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
  - [Less-than (`:lt()`) selector](http://api.jquery.com/less-than-selector/).
  - [`nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).
  - [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
  - [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
  - [`prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/).
  - [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: This doesn't work. Click on 50 on yours and then click of 50 for OP's fiddle and see the difference...

Comment: This great for shortening the code, but if you click anything less than 5 the first 9 (as in his original) are not highlighted (same at the other end). It would still require a conditional test or case.

Comment: Well, guess i'm stuck with conditionals on this one. Thank you for your time sir.

Comment: Well, yeah: conditionals are unavoidable I'm afraid. Though at least there's a plugin now, to take some of your pain away...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [`.slice()`](https://api.jquery.com/slice/), the only thing you have to watch out for is a negative start index which is easy to get around.

```
$(document).on("click", "#footer button", function(){

    var index = $(this).index(),
        range = 9, 
        startIndex = index - range, 
        endIndex = index + ( range + 1 );

    $("#footer button")
        .removeClass('selected')
        .slice(startIndex > 0 ? startIndex : 0, endIndex)
        .addClass('selected');

});
```

Small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/x2QJP/9/